# Building URLs in Go including server scheme

Tags: http, go, https, server, httpserver

I am creating a REST API in Go, and I want to build URLs to other resources in my replies.

Based on the `http.Response` I can get the `Host` and `URL`.

**However, how would I go about getting the transport scheme used by the server? `http` or `https`?**

I attemped to check if `server.TLSConfig` is `nil` and then assuming it is using `http` since it says this in the documentation for `http.Server`:

```
TLSConfig    *tls.Config   // optional TLS config, used by ListenAndServeTLS
```

But it turns out this exists even when I do not run the server with `ListenAndServeTLS`.

---

Or is this way of building my URLs the wrong way of doing things? Is there some other normal way of doing this?

Comment: Why don't you use some framework for this, martini or revel. I am using revel all the time. It supports oauth2 and similar. I played with revel. Here is repo if you are starting from scratch for revel api and oauth2: https://murphy.rs/nikola/revel-oauth2-restful. One more thing, I am always using nginx in front of any app instead running app on 80 and 443 port.

Comment: Well I am not using a big framework since I am trying to learn Go, and want something lightweight, so I settled for `go-restful` after looking at both martini and revel first.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred solution when running http and https is just to run a simple listener on `:80` that redirects all traffic to https. Then any real traffic can be assumed to be https.

Alternately I believe you can access a request's URL at `req.URL.Scheme` to see the protocol.

Or do you mean for the entire application? If you accept configuration to switch between http and https, then can't you look at that and see which they chose? I guess I'm missing some context maybe.

It is also common practice for apps to take a `baseURL` via flag or config to generate external urls with.